# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I'm trying to connect remote SQL Server, when I'm trying to connect with beekeeper software its connected successfully but with laravel its show this error:

> SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired

This is my code

```
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL_SQL_SRV'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST_SQL_SRV', '196.221.165.158'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT_SQL_SRV', '2020'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_SQL_SRV', 'DBname'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_SQL_SRV', 'Username'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_SQL_SRV', 'ServerPassword'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            // 'encrypt' => env('DB_ENCRYPT', 'yes'),
            // 'trust_server_certificate' => env('DB_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'false'),
        ],
```

I'm sure of all the data